# Sending a Mat object over socket from Java to Java

Tags: java, sockets, opencv, mat

I understand Sockets over Java and sending Int,String,bytes etc over it.

What i just want to know is that is there a way to decode a Mat object to byte array and then send it over java socket and then retrieve back the Mat object from the byte received?

> Till Now this is What I have done

## For Sending Mat over socket

```
//Sending Mat over Socket

Mat socketmat;      
long  nbytes = socketmat.total() * socketmat.elemSize();
byte[] bytes = new byte[ (int) nbytes ];
socketmat.get(0, 0,bytes);
mybytearray = bytes;

dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
dos.writeLong(nbytes);
dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);  

dos.flush();
```

## For Receiving Mat over Socket

```
//Receiving Mat over Socket

long len = clientData.readLong();  
byte[] data = new byte[ (int) len];
if (len > 0) {
    clientData.readFully(data);
}            
byte[] bytes_ = data;
result_mat.get(0, 0, bytes_ );
```

Comment: @Newd ..Yes i have mentioned it now

Comment: Have you tried ObjectOutputStream? It'd be a good starting point for you as it takes care of serialization / deserialization automatically.

Comment: Nah...I dont have any idea about serialization/deserialization

Comment: don't try to send a Mat over the wire. instead, imencode() it to a byte array and imdecode() on the other side.

Comment: @berak..How can i do it.....i cant retrieve the same mat back from imdecode() as it will be compressed and changed to .jpg or .png

Comment: Is there anyway to store it in XML/YAML file storages ...like in OpenCV C++......like FileStorage fs("img.xml", FileStorage::WRITE); Mat img; fs << img;

Comment: @SpitCompMe - FileStorage is not available at all from the java wrappers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think is to Save Mat using `FileStorage` class using JNI.

The following code can be used to save Mat as File Storage

```
FileStorage storage("image.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
storage << "img" << mat;
storage.release();
```

Then send the file using Socket and then retrive Mat back from File.

```
FileStorage fs("image.xml", FileStorage::READ);
Mat img;
fs >> img;
```